# 'async void' is okay for event handlers, but what if there is only a virtual method to override?

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, async-await, overriding

Our team uses *Caliburn* and the view models derive from a base class that offers virtual methods to override. For instance `OnActivate()` can be overridden whenever the view is activated. *Caliburn* doesn’t offer an event handler to attach to.
We want to call awaitable functions in `OnActivate()`. This can be done it the following way:

```
protected override async void OnActivate()
{
    base.OnActivate();
    try
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync()           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
  // …
    }
}
```

Although everything works fine, we are in conflict with the best practice, that `async void` may only be applied to event handlers. However, there is no event handler, only a virtual method to override. *Sonarqube* takes notice of this and gives a warning.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already eluded to, this is not best practice and while it "seems" as though everything is working fine -- that will not be the case... you're setting yourself up for a lot of frustration.

> What is the best way to solve this problem?

The best approach varies on the desired function you're trying to accomplish and how long said functionality might take, as well as whether or not anything else specifically relies on this functionality. A wise man once said, "go `async` all the way or go `sync` all the way". I second that!

Some people might feel the urge to explain to you that it's safe to go `async` over `sync` in this situation, but then they would be bending the best practices model too far.

Aligning with best practices I would only ever use `async` / `await` if the `virtual` method that I'm overriding was `Task`, `Task<T>` or another "awaitable" type returning signature.

With that said, and if this is absolutely required I would store the task off as a property and allow other calls that rely on it to `await` it accordingly.

```
public Task MyTask;

protected override void OnActivate()
{
    base.OnActivate();
    try
    {
        MyTask = DoSomethingAsync()           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // …
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere, whether within this class or external to it - if there is code that relies on this to be completed you can `await` it there.

```
async Task ConsumingAsync()
{
    await _instance.MyTask;

    // Now we know the work is done...
}
```

---

Again, this is **not** something I would advise to do. I implore you to consider alternatives.

Comment: _everything is working fine -- that will not be the case... you're setting yourself up for a lot of frustration._

It's not clear to me, which problems for instance? The async call is wrapped in `try catch`, eventual exceptions in the awaitable are handled properly. It’s just the end station (or beginning) of the async await chain.

What is exactly the difference between an event handler and this virtual method opposite? When it is legit for an event handler, why shouldn’t it be legit for a virtual fire-and-forget function with the same signature? I  just don’t get the point…